# Is it possible to use ECharts Baidu with Angular 2 and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, angular, echarts

I am trying to implement EChart Baidu in Angular 2 application (typescript).

I am following the start guide on their website https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts/doc/start-en.html but have no idea how I am supposed to init the chart having no clue about the function parameter of this line of code:

```
function (ec) {
            var myChart = ec.init(document.getElementById('main'));
```

Using Angular 2 I have ngOnInit() function that can be used as jquery's $(document).ready().

I've tries to implement ECharts in a separate page using pure javasript  and is working just fine. I even have HTML theme [Limitless](http://demo.interface.club/limitless/layout_1/LTR/default/echarts_lines_areas.html).

The problem is that I don't know how to get this 'ec' parameter from the code above in Angular2.

Any help would be appreciated! Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, I have found a solution!

First, you should use echarts.js library which is **NOT** common js. I am using [this one](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/echarts/3.2.0/echarts.js) which I have found [here](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/echarts#). Notice that the first two libraries are common.js and common.min.js. They use **require** as a function but typescript has its own require. It is not okay to mess up like that so for clearer solution just use non common js library of echarts.

In the directory where echarts.js file is located, I've created echarts.d.ts which has only one line of code:

```
export function init (elem: any);
```

Then, in my component.ts file I import like this:

```
import * as echarts from 'path/to/echarts/jsfile'
```

You should import without the .js extention!

After that in my onInit function I just do:

```
let basic_lines = echarts.init(document.getElementById(this.chartId));
```

where this.chartId is just the id of my DOM element holding the chart and basic_lines is an object which I fill with options later on (just like in the example given in the question!

I hope this would help someone!

Answer (score 10):

```
npm install --save echarts
npm install --save-dev @types/echarts
```

code：

```
import {
  Directive, ElementRef, Input, OnInit, HostBinding, OnChanges, OnDestroy
} from '@angular/core';

import {Subject, Subscription} from "rxjs";

import * as echarts from 'echarts';
import ECharts = echarts.ECharts;
import EChartOption = echarts.EChartOption;


@Directive({
  selector: '[ts-chart]',
})
export class echartsDirective implements OnChanges,OnInit,OnDestroy {
  private chart: ECharts;
  private sizeCheckInterval = null;
  private reSize$ = new Subject<string>();
  private onResize: Subscription;

  @Input('ts-chart') options: EChartOption;

  @HostBinding('style.height.px')
  elHeight: number;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    this.chart = echarts.init(this.el.nativeElement, 'vintage');
  }


  ngOnChanges(changes) {
    if (this.options) {
      this.chart.setOption(this.options);
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sizeCheckInterval = setInterval(() => {
      this.reSize$.next(`${this.el.nativeElement.offsetWidth}:${this.el.nativeElement.offsetHeight}`)
    }, 100);
    this.onResize = this.reSize$
      .distinctUntilChanged()
      .subscribe((_) => this.chart.resize());

    this.elHeight = this.el.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
    if (this.elHeight < 300) {
      this.elHeight = 300;
    }
  }


  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.sizeCheckInterval) {
      clearInterval(this.sizeCheckInterval);
    }
    this.reSize$.complete();
    if (this.onResize) {
      this.onResize.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```

luck ：)

Comment: Why this dollar at the end of this variables?

Comment: i just had to edit my directive and add `ngOnChanges` and it now works great ! thanks :)

Comment: @Natanael It is a [naming convention](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library#naming-conventions-for-observables) for observables.

Answer (score 2):

I have used：

`import * as echarts from 'path/to/echarts/jsfile'`

but that has a error
  `error TS2307: Cannot find module 'echarts'`

In the end, simple and crude,I have require as a property for the chass:

1.install whith npm module for echarts:

`npm install echarts`

2.defined a property for the class:

```
export class AdvertReportComponent implements OnInit {
     echarts: any = require('echarts')
     ngOnInit(){
       //set options;
       var options= {...};
       var chartView = this.echarts.init(this._chartElement.nativeElement);
       chartView.setOption(options);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first, install the echart via npm

```
npm install --save echarts
```

second, require the echart in your component

```
const echarts = require('echarts');
```

then, in ngInit function, apply your code

```
const selectDom = this.renderer.selectRootElement('#chart');
const myChart = charts.init(selectDom);
```

Answer (score 1):

`npm install -S echarts` 
`npm install -D @types/echarts` 
`npm install -S ngx-echart --save` (the new version of `angular2-echarts`)

`-D = --save-dev`  `-S = --save`

Reference with `@Ng`, `@Component`/@`Directive` in your `.ts` files.
Call into your `pages` - Don't forget to check your `selector`!

`import * as echarts from 'echarts';` (TS(Typescript) not JS filetype)
`import { AngularModuleEcharts } from 'ngx-charts';`

@TossPig's code works fine.

Am using Ionic3 with TS devDependencies with `ngx-echarts`.
Had some problems with converting the Angular Directive to an Ionic Module for reuse.
Check out https://github.com/xieziyu/ngx-echarts and https://xieziyu.github.io/#/ngx-echarts/demo for code structure and implementation as Angular components.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [angular2-echarts](https://github.com/xieziyu/angular2-echarts) library. To install:

```
npm install echarts --save

npm install angular2-echarts --save
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It has been renamed [ngx-echarts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-echarts) since!